# NSAttribtuedStringt From HTML, Override Default Text Color

Tags: html, css, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm getting some HTML-styled text from the server that I need to display as the attributedText of a `UILabel` or `UITextView`.

The html may contain simple `<em>`, `<b>`, `<u>` tags, and also `<font>` tags specifying a different color for sections of the text.

First, I took the simple approach of converting my HTML string to data and using it to initialize an `NSAttributedString` appropriately, using `init(data:options:documentAttributes:)`.

This works as expected, except that it overrides the font of the text view to some what seems to be a very tiny Times New Roman.

Based on code found on [this blog post](https://medium.com/@valv0/a-swift-extension-for-string-and-html-8cfb7477a510), I decided to prepend a style tag to the whole thing so that I could set the default font family and point size:

```
func htmlAttributed(family: String?, size: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString? {

    do {
        let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
            "html *" +
            "{" +
            "font-size: \(size)pt !important;" +
            "font-family: \(family ?? "Helvetica"), Helvetica !important;" +
        "}</style> \(self)"

        guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        return try NSAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

The original code had an additional argument to specify the **text color** in the prepended `<style>` tag, but I removed it because my html content specifies text color inside separate `<font>` tags within the text.

This gets the job done, but I have a problem left: The text's default color is rendered black, and I need it to be a lighter shade of gray.

If I reinstante the color parameter to the style tag:

```
let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
            "html *" +
            "{" +
            "font-size: \(size)pt !important;" +
            "color: #\(color.hexString) !important;" + // <- THIS
            "font-family: \(family ?? "Helvetica"), Helvetica !important;" +
        "}</style> \(self)"
```

then the whole text gets the same color, and inline tags such as:

```
<font color="FF0000">red text</font>
```

are ignored.

---

**How can I specify a default color different than black, and still have a per-segment color using `<font>` tags?**

Comment: why you need !important everywhere??

Comment: @Overflowrun I'm not very CSS-savvy; I took that code from the linked blog post as-is.

Comment: oh :) np !important is will overwrite everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove that `!important` from the code and replace `<font>` tag with `<span>`

Comment: Indeed, I figured out that replacing `<font color=...` with an equivalent `<span style="color: ...` does the trick. Right now I'm having trouble with the string replacement code (I think I'm wrongly escaping some double quotes) but when I hard-coded the span, it worked.

Comment: Font is an old HTML tag which is not there anymore available.